# Android app crashes when opening the system settings screen

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

In our application, we use a post-opt-in popup to ask users who were previously opted out of push notifications to allow them. We redirect users to the system notification settings of the app. On android, this causes the app to terminate, but the settings screen opens successfully. Below is an example of how we redirect to the settings screen. I couldn't find any useful information on this problem. I hope experienced android developers can help.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class NotificationSettings {
    public static void open() {
        Context context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
        } else {
            // Fallback for devices running Android 7.1 or lower
            intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null));
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I'm expect, that android will not kill app after redirecting to system settings screen.

Comment: What does the error say? Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The app may crash because redirecting to the system settings can sometimes cause the system to clear the current task or consider the app expendable, leading to its termination to reclaim resources. which cause some device to crash

try to add flags to the intent that opens the system settings

```
public class NotificationSettings {
public static void open() {
    Context context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    Intent intent = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) ?
        new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName()) :
        new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                .setData(Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null));

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    context.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: It was found that the original problem was quite different and not related to the error I described. Thank you for your participation! In any case, your reply contains very valuable information. I'm really appreciate your help!